# How to get absolute path from Android gridview thumbnail?

Tags: android, gridview, thumbnails, filepath

I am developing an android video gallery application. I managed to fetch all the thumbnails from storage and show them in a grid-view. But now, how can I get the original video file path by clicking each thumbnail ?

Here is my code :

```
mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                    mGridView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(
                                        AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                        View view, int i, long l) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video Path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
```

Comment: How did you fetch the thumbnails from gallery and passed to adapter. Show us more code.

Comment: The poor mans way of doing it is to Add a Textview (with width and height "0dp" so its hidden in your gridview items, give an id of path)  in your listrow items layout assuming you are inflating. Set the video path  as text. Then grab the text for that TextView (gridview item) using  its id  iinside your click listener. easy peasy.